# How to rename command to avoid double defined command names

Tags: algorithmicx

Hy,
I would like to use the packages `vaucanson` and `algorithm`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{vaucanson-g}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{code}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{a}{$G,r,t$}
   \State $a \gets g$
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{postscript}[scale=0.6]\special{header=gastex.pro}   
  \begin{VCPicture}{(0,-2)(6,2)}
  \State[s_0]{(0,0)}{0}
  \FinalState[s_2]{(3,1)}{1}
  \EdgeL{0}{1}{t}
\end{VCPicture}
\end{postscript}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\State` is already defined in `vaucanson` and I get

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \State already defined
```

Is it possible to simply rename one of the \State commands to avoid the conflict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After loading `algorithm`, and before loading `vaucanson-g`, put a

```
\let\MyState\State
\let\State\relax
```

Then you can use `\MyState` as the `\State` from `algorithm`, and `vaucanson-g` can define `\State` afresh, avoiding the error. (Thanks, @egreg !)

Comment: Also `\let\State\relax` is necessary after that, to avoid the error.

Comment: Also don't be tempted to swap the definition back after loading `vaucanson-g`, as that package uses its `\State` command internally in other commands.

Comment: @dziadgba I edited the answer to make it complete.